# Delphi 7: How to insert a line in TMemo box into TEdit

Tags: delphi-7

Hello I am a beginner with Delphi. How do I insert a line in my TMemo into the TEdit?

Currently have

```pascal
procedure TForm1.tt_memoloadTimer(Sender: TObject);
  //Load the contents of the words.txt into the Memo Box
begin
  mem_boxTlist.Lines.LoadFromFile('G:\My Drive\L3DGP_Mortel_Kian_(18365)\Guess A Word\Project\words.txt');
end;
```

[image: See below]

When a user clicks on a line, it should be inserted into the TEdit.

Comment: TMemo is a multi-line control. TEdit is a single-line control. It is not clear what exactly you want to display in the TEdit. Please clarify what you really want.

Comment: Hi kloss. Once a question is posted, please do not vandalise it. In some cases it is permitted to delete it, though I think you can't in this case, since it has an upvoted answer. I would generally recommend not deleting if it has any good answer, even if that answer has not been upvoted - remember that good answers have volunteer effort behind them, and it's not fair to delete that person's work.

Answer (score 1):

- mem_boxTlist.lines is the list of strings in the memo.
- mem_boxTlist.lines[i] is the string at the ith index in
  mem_boxTlist.lines.
- mem_boxTlist.caretPos.Y is the index of line that the cursor is on.

If you are trying to insert the word clicked on in the memo, into the textbox, do this inside the onclick event of the memo:

```
procedure TfrmMain.mem_boxTlistClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  editBox.text := mem_boxTlist.lines[mem_boxTlist.caretPos.Y];
end;
```